# speeding up numpy.dot inside list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, numpy, list-comprehension, dot-product

I have a numpy script that is currently running quite slowly.
spends the vast majority of it's time performing the following operation inside a loop:

```
terms=zip(Coeff_3,Coeff_2,Curl_x,Curl_y,Curl_z,Ex,Ey,Ez_av)
res=[np.dot(C2,array([C_x,C_y,C_z]))+np.dot(C3,array([ex,ey,ez])) for (C3,C2,C_x,C_y,C_z,ex,ey,ez) in terms]
res=array(res) 

Ex[1:Nx-1]=res[1:Nx-1,0]
Ey[1:Nx-1]=res[1:Nx-1,1]
```

It's the list comprehension that is really slowing this code down.
In this case, Coeff_3, and Coeff_2 are length 1000 lists whose elements are 3x3 numpy matricies, and Ex,Ey,Ez, Curl_x, etc are all length 1000 numpy arrays.
I realize it might be faster if i did things like setting a single 3x1000 E vector, but i have to perform a significant amount of averaging of different E vectors between step, which would make things very unwieldy.

Curiously however, i perform this operation twice per loop (once for Ex,Ey, once for Ez), and performing the same operation for the Ez's takes almost twice as long:

```
terms2=zip(Coeff_3,Coeff_2,Curl_x,Curl_y,Curl_z,Ex_av,Ey_av,Ez)
res2=array([np.dot(C2,array([C_x,C_y,C_z]))+np.dot(C3,array([ex,ey,ez])) for (C3,C2,C_x,C_y,C_z,ex,ey,ez) in terms2])
```

Anyone have any idea what's happening? Forgive me if it's anything obvious, i'm very new to python.

Comment: You should write the list comprehension as an array operation

Comment: How so? I'm not really sure how to do it/

Comment: If you can rewrite this operation using n-dimensional tensors and einstein summation notation it will be trivial to vectorize the operation in numpy. At the very least please write the dimension of each object. For example "Coeff_3" appears to be of shape (1000,3,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in previous comments, use array operations. `np.hstack()`, `np.vstack()`, `np.outer()` and `np.inner()` are useful here. You're code could become something like this (not sure about your dimensions):

```
 Cxyz = np.vstack((Curl_x,Curl_y,Curl_z))
 C2xyz = np.dot(C2, Cxyz)
 ...
```

Check the shape of your resulting dimensions, to make sure you translated your problem right. Sometimes [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) can also to speed up such tasks significantly with little extra effort,

Comment: This seems to work. I've stacked all my vectors and used einstein summation as suggested by Option and it has gone from 15 cycles per second to 77 cycles per second. Thanks!